# Can a surjective morphism between complete intersection rings be given by adding terms to a regular sequence?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, complete-intersection

Given a surjective morphism

$$\frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{I}\twoheadrightarrow \frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{J}$$

where $I,J$ are genereated by regular sequences.

**Question**

Can we find a regular sequence $f_{1},\dots,f_{k},\dots,f_{l}$ such that there exist a commutative square

$$\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{I} & \twoheadrightarrow & \frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{J} \\ 
\downarrow\simeq & & \downarrow\simeq \\ 
\frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{f_{1},\dots,f_{k}} & \twoheadrightarrow  & \frac{\mathcal{O}[[X_{1},\dots ,X_{n}]]}{f_{1},\dots,f_{l}} , \end{array}$$

Comment: No. Take the case of two variables $ x,y$. Take $ I=( x^2,y^2)$ and $J=( x,y)$.